# NodeJS Express sendFile that includes external JS files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, I have a file structure like this:

```
App
 client
   index.html
   App.js
 server
   node_modules
   package.json
   server.js
```

the server.js is the server file ran by node, it serves up the index.html

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);



app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile("client/index.html",{ root: '../' });
});




http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

So the index.html includes the App.js in it's head, like you normally would

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="App.js"></script>
```

The problem is, that App.js is never found and included when I connect. Gives a 404. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one solved mine. You can check this out.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
```

Thus, my **app.js** can be accessed via -> http://localhost:3000/js/app.js

Answer (score 1):

Your server doesn't seem to do anything but sending `client/index.html` when `http://127.0.0.1:3000` is requested in a browser.
So what actually happens, when the browser received the index.html, it sends another request to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/App.js`. But your Server can't answere that request. It can only anwere requests for the index. If you want a static server check out serve-static on Github:
https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static
Or you could write another route for you app anwering with the App.js as you did for the `index.html`.

Comment: Another route? do you mean just adding a new res.sendFile into there, or making a whole new app.get ? With what? The same "/" or ?

Comment: I mean another `app.get()` or changing you existing route to for example `/:file` and using `req.params.file` to get the file name.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your server folder structure you need to access using the path ./client/App.js, instead of only App.js

So your script tag will look like,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./client/App.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you set the static folder for express?

Comment: No, how would I do that?

Comment: I tried like this `var express= require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use("./client/",express.static('../client/'));` and it still tries to load a http://localhost:3000/client/App.js , which gives a 404

Comment: you need to set the express static like this: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../client')); and not app.use("./client/",express.static('../client/'));